# Compare ArrayCollection with array of objects

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have a StatColle entity in a ManyToMany relationship with a Groupe entity.
I want to compare an array of Groupe objects with an arrayCollection.

Here's my code :

```
//Create array of Groupe objects
$nameOfSelectedGroupes = $request->request->get('selectedGroupes');

        $groupes= [];
        foreach ($nameOfSelectedGroupes as $nameOfSelectedGroupe) {
            $groupe = $em->getRepository(Groupe::class)->findBy(['nom' => $nameOfSelectedGroupe]);
            $groupes[] = $groupe;
        }

// Compare array of objects with ArrayCollection of objects
...request to get StatColle...
foreach ($resultats as $resultat)
    {
        if ($groupes == $resultat->getGroupes()->toArray())
        return $resultat;
    }
...
```

This is always returning null. I think that `$resultat->getGroupes()->toArray()` is not the correct way to get Groupes linked to StatColle entity.

Do you have an idea to compare these arrays ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't compare arrays like that. Try [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php), and then check if the resultant array is [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) (means they are the same):

```
foreach ($resultats as $resultat){
    $compare = array_diff($groupes, $resultat->getGroupes()->toArray());
    if (empty($compare)){
        return $resultat;
    }
}
```

I think that should work.

Comment: I tried but I have an error : Object of class Groupe could not be converted to string. When I dump `$resultat->getGroupes()->toArray()`, I have an array of Groupe objects.

Comment: I think array_diff can't be used for arrays of objects.

Comment: I guess one way to debug is to use `var_dump` or `print_r` to compare the two arrays `$groupes` and one of the `$resultat` arrays. Maybe the way you are creating `groupes[]` is incorrect?

Comment: Are you sure that `$resultat->getGroupes` returns an ArrayCollection? I see that the [toArray() method of ArrayCollection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html) does return a PHP array. So using `array_diff` is the correct way to do this. The problem seems to be where the error `Object of class Groupe could not be converted to string` comes from. You need to isolate which line in your code it comes from.

Comment: `$resultat->getGroupes` returns an ArrayCollection.
`$resultat->getGroupes->toArray` returns a PHP array of Groupe objects (like $groupes array).
I can paste here the dumped arrays if you want

Comment: Then my code above should work! Figure out which line of code the error is coming from. Re-edit your post if you haven't included relevant information. I suspect you are missing something important.

Comment: I used a little trick : I created an array of ids of `$groupes` and an array of ids of `$resultat->getGroupe->toArray`.
I used `array_diff` on these 2 new arrays and it's working.
Thanks for your help !